# issue in remove # from url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase

remove # from url using

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

and display error

[$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$location/nobase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to mention base to your html document.
$location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present! see documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

```
<base href="/">
```